# Is there a way to check if users of different chat accounts are the same person?

Tags: youtube-api

I am using "LiveChatMessages" to get Youtube chat messages.
Is there a way to check from the ChannelID or ChannelURL of each chat message whether those messages were sent from the same person or from the same PC?

Thanks.

Comment: For privacy reason, it's clear that you can't for any pair of channel ids say whether or not the same person is controlling both.

Comment: I knew it.
Thanks.